# Ionic 3: Local images don't display on Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using a pipe in my Ionic 3 app to modify the URLs of locally captured images so that they can be displayed in an `<img>` tag. This works perfectly in iOS.

However on Android, I tun into the following error in my remote web inspector: `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///data/user/0/com.example.mobile/files/1527609310822.jpg`. I even get this issue after running my URL through DomSanitizer (see code below).

**What I've tried:**

I set up a pipe to correctly modify local URLs to display in templates. On iOS it uses `normalizeUrl`, on Android it uses `DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl`:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { normalizeURL, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'localImage',
})
export class LocalImagePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private platform: Platform, private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  transform(url) {
    console.log('input:', url);
    let result;
    if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      result = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
    } else {
      result = normalizeURL(url);
    }

    console.log('output', JSON.stringify(result));
    return result;
  }
}
```

iOS URLs going into the pipe:

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/325C2BBA-FCA9-4838-974F-9F84BDF2F6F5/Library/NoCloud/1527606661016.jpg
```

iOS URLs coming out of the pipe **(works):**

```
http://localhost:8080/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/325C2BBA-FCA9-4838-974F-9F84BDF2F6F5/Library/NoCloud/1527606661016.jpg
```

Android URLs going into the pipe **(files are known to exist):**

```
file:///data/user/0/com.example.mobile/files/1527606953669.jpg
```

Android URLs coming out of the pipe:

`{"changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.mobile/files/1527606953669.jpg"}`

**What happens:**

1) I try using `DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl()` on Android. I get an error: `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///data/user/0/com.example.mobile/files/1527611495217.jpg`.

2) I try using `DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl()`. Same thing.

3) I try just returning the base URL on Android (`file:///data/user/0/com.example.mobile/files/1527611495217.jpg`): Same thing.

My template:

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-col col-6 *ngFor="let m of media">
    <img [src]="m | localImage">
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

In my index.html, I have the following just in case:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" img-src '*'>
```

Comment: is there any error or warning re this for you? Whenever I worked with images in similar to yours context (instead of camera I was creating raster images of html canvas as blobs and then was rendering those) I had to deal with Angular security issues (use DOMSanitizer for all image URLs). I wonder if your change in meta actually resolves these type of issues on Android.

Comment: Yes, I get the error `:8100/#/tabs/media/add:1 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///data/user/0/com.example.mobile/files/1527606953669.jpg`

Comment: Try using DOMSanitizer - https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer. I think you need this one: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl

Comment: I modified my pipe to use `DOMSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl` on Android, but I'm still getting the same error. I'll update my question with more details.

Comment: Did you try bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl? and you say the error message is exactly the same? can you also try to generate a url: file:///data/user/0/com.example.mobile/files/1527606953669.jpg and use it without binding in your template and see if it renders.

Comment: I've tried `bypassSecurityTrustUrl` (which is the one you're supposed to use for links or `img` resources), as well as bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl which is meant for `script` and `iframe` tags. Using either of these (or just the base `file://` url) results in the same error.

Comment: I found the issue. When in livereload mode, the app is unable to access images stored on the device. Emulating the app in normal mode and using `DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl()` works!

Comment: Noice! Good and ty i also learned a bit

Comment: I'm dealing with the same problem. Could you find solution to this?

Comment: @shehatesme See my comment directly upthread for an explanation of what my problem turned out to be and how I fixed it :)